# Retrive Triggered Send Information by RequestID

Tags: marketing-cloud

We perform lots of triggered sends from our `.NET` code and we store `RequestID` in our database.

I need take that `RequestID` and request ExactTarget to **get the details about that particular Triggered Send** by `RequestID`.

**How can I do this?**

What I see in the documentation is - [Retrieving a Triggered Send Summary](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_a_triggered_send_summary/)

Here is the code sample:

```
RetrieveRequest rr = new RetrieveRequest();
rr.ObjectType = "TriggeredSendSummary";
rr.Properties = new String[] { "Sent", "Bounces", "Opens", "Clicks" };

TriggeredSendSummary tss = new TriggeredSendSummary(); // <=== THIS IS NOT USED. WHY IS IT HERE???

SimpleFilterPart sfp = new SimpleFilterPart();
sfp.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals;
sfp.Property = "CustomerKey"; // <=== ONLY CUSTOMER KEY
sfp.Value = new string[] { "Weekly_Newsletter_-_2009_07_16" }; 

rr.Filter = sfp;

string requestID;

APIObject[] results;

string status = client.Retrieve(rr, out requestID, out results);

return results;
```

There is only filter by customer key, not RequestID.

Can you help me with this?

**UPD1:** Why is **`TriggeredSendSummary`** here? It is not used...

Comment: Have you tried changing `CustomerKey` to `RequestID`, and passing in  valid id?

Comment: Yes, it returns ApiObject[0] - means zero results.

Comment: UPDATE: RequestID in filter returns error: The Filter propery does not match fields of the view. And that's obvious, since TriggeredSendSummary does not has this prop: http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/triggeredsendsummary/

Comment: `RequestID` is the id you would get back from the actual SOAP call.  I don't think you will actually be able to do anything with that specifically.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get tracking for individual triggered sends, you would need to look at [this help article](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_tracking_results_for_one_to_one_triggered_sends/).

Essentially, you will need to turn on send logging in your account, then do the following steps:

1. Create a new profile attribute - the example code below names the
   attribute UniqueID, but you can change the name as appropriate.
2. Modify your existing send Log data extension to have a field named
   UniqueID.
3. Update an existing triggered send definition or create a new one,
   and be sure to set the IsSendLogging property to true.
4. Trigger an email using the triggered send definition from step 4
   with Send Logging passing in a value for the UniqueID attribute.
5. Use the Retrieve method to retrieve the JobID, BatchID, and
   SubscriberID for that specific send from the send log data
   extension.

Comment: Would it allow me to see whether the triggered email was sent or not? When it was sent and some other info / statistics?

Comment: Yes - that will provide detail regarding that specific send.

Comment: Sorry - the send log itself will not give you the details - but you can match the jobid, and subscriberid to retrieve the tracking events through the api.  This is helping you get the specific details to get that tracking info.